# Location services with expo-location

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a ecommerce delivery app with Expo, React Native. When the app loads for the first time it fetches the location , but I am facing two problems here

1. When the location permission is denied
   2 When the location is tuned off in the device

If permission is denied I am able to ask to enable by using `Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync`
But how should I make the user turn on the location setting.

Answer (score 1):

Expo provides `Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync()` to determine whether location services are enabled.

In case of being disabled, you should ask the user to enable those services manually and clearly describe the intention of your app to access her/his location.